# Не могу понять задание

Tags: алгоритм

Хочу выполнить тестовое задание.
Проблема в том, что я не могу понять его **второй** пункт.

То ли я корявый, то ли формулировка задания не точная. Если уважаемые участники форума пояснят, что там имеется в виду - буду благодарен.

Вот само задание:

> **Разработать алгоритм который:**
>
> Сортирует переданный список записей (каждая запись - набор колонок)
>   таблицы по указанной колонке по следующим правилам:
>
> 1) в колонке могут быть **null** и пустые значения - строки с
>   **null**-значениями должны быть первыми,    затем строки с пустым значением, затем все остальные.
>
> 2) строка бьется на подстроки следующим образом:
>
> Выделяем **непрерывные** **максимальные** фрагменты строки,
>   состоящие только из цифр,    и считаем набором подстрок эти фрагменты
>   и все оставшиеся от такого разбиения фрагменты строки.
>
> 3)  при сравнении строк осуществляется последовательное сравнение их
>   подстрок до первого несовпадения,
>
> 4)  если обе подстроки состоят из цифр - то при сравнении они
>   интерпретируются как целые числа (вначале должно идти меньшее число), 
>   в противном случае - как строки,  сортировка должна быть устойчива к
>   исходной сортировке списка - т.е.,    если строки (в контексте
>   указанных правил сравнения) неразличимы, то сортировка не должна
>   менять их местами.

По **2)** пункту:
Я не совсем понимаю, как могут быть максимальными фрагмент**Ы** строки. Максимальным (по длине) может быть только один фрагмент?!

Что в понимании постановщика задачи есть "**строка**"? Это совокупность столбцов одной записи или же это **значение столбца** по которому нужно сортировать список?

Comment: Было бы не плохо увидеть пример данных с которыми будет работать этот алгоритм.

Comment: Кажется лучше спросить у того кто давал задание, а то неясно, какой ответ будет правильным. Понять задание каждый может по своему.

Comment: Я так и сделал, но "в ответ тишина.."(с)

Comment: Я тоже хочу увидеть пример данных, но по условию задачи, этим набором данных может быть результат Select-а (к примеру) Т.е. это список одномерных массивов, где записи - это элементы списка(массивы), а столбцы - это элементы одномерного массива.

Comment: По описанию выглядит как хранение csv в базе и соответственно сортировка по этому полю. Правильное решение в данном случае - приведение бд хотя бы к первой нормальной форме, а "алгоритм-костыль" таки реализовать и высечь на могиле автора задания.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Речь о таком разбиении:

```
11х1111хххх1ххх1
["11", "х", "1111", "хххх", "1", "ххх", "1"]
```

Под "максимальные" понимается "жадное совпадение" при котором совпадение старается захватить как можно больше символов. **Совпадений по каждой строке может быть больше одного, и каждое из них должно захватывать как можно больше**. *Максимальное* относится к *каждому* фрагменту, а не ко всему набору.

Это разбиение **однозначно**, т. е. для каждой строки существует ровно одно такое.

**Если это условие убрать из задачи**, появятся дополнительные разбиения, в которых непрерывные последовательности из цифр раскиданы по отдельным фрагментам, типа:

```
11ххх11111хх
["1", "1", "xxx", "11", "111", "xx"]
```

Поэтому наложено условие при разборе каждого фрагмента брать максимально возможное число символов. Одно из непосредственных следствий, таким образом: два последовательных фрагмента не могут оба состоять из цифр, т. к. они должны быть захвачены в один фрагмент.

Comment: Ну вот к примеру такое выражение: 111ххх222223334455хх - это первая строка и xxx2222xxxx11 - это вторая. Теперь смотрим: в первой строке максимальное совпадение это "222223334455". Во второй строке - это "2222". Переводим их в числа. Получим 2222 и 222223334455 соответственно. Следуя условию задачи, строка с 2222 должна быть первой, а строка с 222223334455 - второй. Но это же не правильно! Первой должна быть строка "111ххх222223334455хх" где первые символы единицы - т.е. 111 Иначе это уже не сортировка а что-то другое.

Comment: @Vard32 вы вообще не поняли ответ. Сейчас подумаю, как его прояснить...

Comment: Да, я чувствую что не понял. Если Вам не сложно - поясните пож-ста.

Comment: @Vard32 во, посмотрите сейчас.

Comment: Смотрю +  Думаю.

Comment: Поясните пож-ста: что есть "строка" в контексте условия этой задачи? Это значение поля или совокупность значений столбцов по одной записи?

Comment: @Vard32 думаю, что это **значение столбца**. Разбиение нужно выполнить для **каждой** записи для сравнения их между собой.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, почему в Вашем первом примере строки, разбиение выглядит как ["11", "х", "1111", "хххх", "1", "ххх1"] а не ["11", "х", "1111", "хххх", "1", "ххх", "1"] ?

Comment: @Vard32 ошибочка вышла, извините %) Сейчас подкручу.

Comment: Т.е. (если я правильно понял) На входе у меня есть строка (значение поля столбца) Например такое: "xx222cc1111vv555555bb77". После выполнения пункта 2 у меня должен получиться массив из ["xx", "222", "cc", "1111", "vv", "555555", "bb", "77"] ?

Comment: @Vard32 да, всё так.

Comment: И при сравнении двух соседних записей (читай двух "распарсеных" строк в массивы) я буду сравнивать два массива разного размера?

Comment: @Vard32 совершенно верно.

Comment: Так получается, что в сортировке, исключительно символьные фрагменты участвовать не будут?

Comment: @Vard32 будут, см. п. 4.

Comment: Теперь более менее понятно! Спасибо Вам! ) Приятно общаться с умным человеком!